# Double odds of one outcome, what should happen to the other outcomes?

Tags: odds-ratio, odds

When you have a binomial outcome, doubling the odds of one outcome halves the odds of the other outcome. E.g. if I have a weighted coin that doubles the odds of heads, it halves the odds of tails.

If I have, say, a 6 sided weighted dice that doubles the odds of a 6, it halves the odds of *anything but 6*, but it decreases the odds of rolling *a particular number other than 6* to $OR*5/6$.

More generally, given a probability distribution of n outcomes each with $p=1/n$, we can construct a new probability distribution of n outcomes in which one outcome has $p=x/(x+n-1)$, and the other n-1 outcomes each have $p=1/(x+n-1)$. The odds ratio of the one outcome will be $OR=x$, and the odds ratio of each of the n-1 outcomes will be $OR=(n-1)/(n+x-2)$.

My question is how to do this when the underlying probability distribution is not uniform. For example, suppose I have a 4-sided die with sides a, b, c, d, and that p(a)=0.25, p(b)=0.5, p(c)=0.15, p(d)=0.1. Now suppose I weight the die such that I double the odds of p(c). Thus, $p(c_{loaded}) = 6/23 = 0.26$. Assuming that my weight did not unfairly influence the probability of any other outcome, what would be the odds ratio for each of these outcomes?

One way to do this would be to make e.g. $p(a_{loaded})=p(a)*(1-p(c_{loaded}))/(1-p(c))$. This would make p(a)=0.22, p(b)=0.43, p(d)=0.09. This would make the relative risks each be equal, e.g. $p(a_{loaded})/p(a)=p(b_{loaded})/p(b)=0.87$. However, the odds ratios would not be equal, e.g. $OR_a=0.83$ whereas $OR_b=0.77$.

Alternatively, another way to do this would be to make the odds ratios be equal. This would be approx $OR_{a,b,d}=0.806$, so e.g. $p(a_{loaded})=0.21$. I do not have any idea how to derive this odds ratio mathematically, I just found it by plugging in numbers until the probability distribution summed to 1. How can I get a closed-form expression that yields "0.806" when you input the original probabilities for a,b,c,d, and the odds ratio of 2 for outcome c?